# Transferring files from local machine to virtual machine

Tags: machine-learning, virtual-machine

I'm trying out a few services that provide GPUs for model training. I'm currently using datacrunch.io. I'm trying to figure out how to upload files from my local machine to the datacrunch instance. On their website, they say that "You can use any program that supports SFTP; WinSCP or Filezilla are popular options.". So, I provided a ssh key while creating the instance, and trying to transfer files using WinSCP by providing the IP of the instance as the host. It seems to be asking me for a username and password, which I have no idea of. If anyone has used datacrunch.io, or similar services, can they please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

In WinSCP you need to link to your SSH private keyfile as well since authentication is only possible via SSH key. The password field must be left blank;
[Check this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nQDv.png)